# Laravel 8 database query - How do I build this collection of related data?

Tags: php, database, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to figure out how to form my database query to build up a collection of projects, each of which has a set of personnel with their assigned working periods and the daily shift hours that they submit.

In the code I have so far, I select the projects that are running for the current month. For each of those I select the personnel that are working on the project during that month. Then for each of the personnel I make another 2 queries to get their assignment dates and submitted shift details.

This does work, and creates the data structure I want, but it's slow due to the large number of individual database queries.

There must be a more efficient way to do this through subqueries or something?

```
$projects = Project::select([
    'projects.id',
    'projects.name',
    'projects.start',
    'projects.finish'
])
->where('projects.start', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth())
->where('projects.finish', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
->get();

foreach($projects as $project)
{
    $project->personnel = ProjectUser::select([
        'project_users.id',
        'project_users.user_id',
        'users.name',
        'project_users.role'
    ])
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'project_users.user_id')
    ->join('assignments', 'assignments.project_user_id', '=', 'project_users.id')
    ->where('project_users.project_id', $project->id)
    ->where('assignments.start', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth())
    ->where('assignments.finish', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
    ->distinct('users.name')
    ->get();

    foreach($project->personnel as $person)
    {
        $person->assignments = Assignment::select([
            'assignments.start',
            'assignments.finish',
            'assignments.travel_out',
            'assignments.travel_home'
        ])
        ->where('assignments.project_user_id', $person->project_user_id)
        ->get();

        $person->shifts = WorkShift::select([
            'work_shifts.id',
            'work_shifts.role',
            'work_shifts.date',
            'work_shifts.start',
            'work_shifts.hours',
            'work_shifts.status',
            'work_shifts.remarks'
        ])
        ->where('work_shifts.user_id', $person->user_id)
        ->where('work_shifts.project_id', $project->id)
        ->get();
    }
}
```

### Update

I now have this mostly working through the use of model relationships. My last problem is that I can filter the projects within a date range at the top level in my controller, but I also need to apply that filter to the assignments and work_shifts.

So, I only want to retrieve project_users that have assignments within the requested date range and then pick out only the assignments and work_shifts that match.

What I have so far is...

```
// Controller
public function load(Request $request)
{
  $projects = Project::select([
    Project::ID,
    Project::NAME,
    Project::START,
    Project::FINISH
  ])
    // Only able to filter by date range here?!?
    ->where(Project::START, '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfYear())
    ->where(Project::FINISH, '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfYear())
    ->with('project_staff')
    ->orderBy(Project::START)
    ->get();

  return response()->json([
    'projects' => $projects
  ]);
}

// Project Model
// Just want to get the staff that are assigned to the project
// between the selected date range
public function project_staff()
{
  return $this->hasMany(ProjectUser::class)
    ->select([
      ProjectUser::ID,
      ProjectUser::PROJECT_ID,
      ProjectUser::USER_ID,
      User::NAME,
      ProjectUser::ROLE
    ])
    ->whereIn(ProjectUser::STATUS, [
      ProjectUser::STATUS_RESERVED,
      ProjectUser::STATUS_ASSIGNED,
      ProjectUser::STATUS_ACCEPTED
    ])
    ->join(User::TABLE, User::ID, '=', ProjectUser::USER_ID)
    ->with([
      'assignments',
      'shifts'
    ]);
}

// Assignments Model
// Again, just want the assignments and workshifts that fall
// within the selected date range
public function assignments()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Assignment::class, 'projectUser_id')
    ->select([
      Assignment::PROJECT_USER_ID,
      Assignment::START,
      Assignment::FINISH,
      Assignment::TRAVEL_OUT,
      Assignment::TRAVEL_HOME
    ]);
}

public function shifts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(WorkShift::class, ['project_id','user_id'], ['project_id','user_id'])
    ->select([
      WorkShift::ID,
      WorkShift::USER_ID,
      WorkShift::PROJECT_ID,
      WorkShift::ROLE,
      WorkShift::DATE,
      WorkShift::START,
      WorkShift::HOURS,
      WorkShift::STATUS,
      WorkShift::REMARKS
    ]);
}

// WorkShift Model
public function projectUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectUser::class, ['project_id','user_id'], ['project_id','user_id']);
}
```

Comment: This probably can be done via Relationships. Do you have Relationships defined between your various Models, like `Project`, `User`, `Assignment` and `WorkShift`? You're correct that this will be slow, as any time you need to run queries in a loop, you hit what's know as an N+1 query issue; you have X Project(s) > Y ProjectUser(s) > Z1 Assignment(s) and Z2 WorkShift(s), which can be as few as 4, or as many as... well, _a lot_ of queries. I think you can probably do some kind of `Project::with(['users.assignments', 'users.workshifts'])->get()`, once you have the relationships defined.

Comment: @Tim Lewis Thank you for your excellent suggestion. I didn't mention it above, but I had looked at using relationships. Unfortunately, I couldn't get my head around how to achieve that with the complexity of the queries and multiple layers of nesting   : (   I will take another look at it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of much learning, the solution I've found is to have very simple relationships between the models and implement all the additional query logic in filter functions attached to the relationship query when it's called using *with*().

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

My code is now working far more efficiently, making only 4 calls to the database in about 10-20ms in my dev-env, and structuring the results data in the correct form to simply return the whole collection as a JSON response.

```
// Controller
public function load(Request $request)
{
  $start = Carbon::parse($request->input('start_date'));
  $end = Carbon::parse($request->input('end_date'));

  $projects = Project::select([
    Project::ID,
    Project::NAME,
    Project::START,
    Project::FINISH
  ])
    ->where(Project::START, '<=', $end)
    ->where(Project::FINISH, '>=', $start)
    ->with([
      // Filter results of the model relationship, passing $start and
      // $end dates down to propagate through to the nested layers
      'project_staff' => $this->filter_project_staff($start, $end)
    ])
    ->orderBy(Project::START)
    ->get();

    return response()->json([
      'projects' => $projects
    ]);
}

private function filter_project_staff($start, $end)
{
  return function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
    $query
      ->select([
        ProjectUser::ID,
        ProjectUser::PROJECT_ID,
        ProjectUser::USER_ID,
        User::NAME,
        ProjectUser::ROLE
      ])
      ->whereIn(ProjectUser::STATUS, [
        ProjectUser::STATUS_RESERVED,
        ProjectUser::STATUS_ASSIGNED,
        ProjectUser::STATUS_ACCEPTED
      ])
      ->join(User::TABLE, User::ID, '=', ProjectUser::USER_ID)
      ->join(Assignment::TABLE, Assignment::PROJECT_USER_ID, '=', ProjectUser::ID)
      ->where(Assignment::START, '<=', $end)
      ->where(Assignment::FINISH, '>=', $start)
      ->distinct(User::NAME)
      ->orderBy(ProjectUser::ROLE, 'desc')
      ->orderBy(User::NAME)
      ->with([
        // Filter results of the nested model relationships
        'assignments' => $this->filter_assignments($start, $end),
        'shifts' => $this->filter_shifts($start, $end)
      ]);
  };
}

private function filter_assignments($start, $end)
{
  return function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
    $query->select([
      Assignment::PROJECT_USER_ID,
      Assignment::START,
      Assignment::FINISH,
      Assignment::TRAVEL_OUT,
      Assignment::TRAVEL_HOME
    ])
      ->where(Assignment::START, '<=', $end)
      ->where(Assignment::FINISH, '>=', $start)
      ->orderBy(Assignment::START);
  };
}

private function filter_shifts($start, $end)
{
  return function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
    $query->select([
      WorkShift::ID,
      WorkShift::USER_ID,
      WorkShift::PROJECT_ID,
      WorkShift::ROLE,
      WorkShift::DATE,
      WorkShift::START,
      WorkShift::HOURS,
      WorkShift::STATUS,
      WorkShift::REMARKS
    ])
      ->where(WorkShift::DATE, '>=', $start)
      ->where(WorkShift::DATE, '<=', $end)
      ->orderBy(WorkShift::DATE);
  };
}

///////////////
//Project Model
public function project_staff(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectUser::class);
}

////////////////////
// ProjectUser Model
public function project(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

public function assignments(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Assignment::class, 'projectUser_id');
}

public function shifts()
{
    // Using awobaz/compoships to simplify creating the relationship using a composite key
    return $this->hasMany(WorkShift::class, ['project_id','user_id'], ['project_id','user_id']);
}

///////////////////
// Assignment Model
public function project_user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectUser::class, 'projectUser_id');
}


// WorkShift Model
public function project_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectUser::class, ['project_id','user_id'], ['project_id','user_id']);
}
```

Many thanks to anyone that put time and thought into helping me with this problem. Your effort is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can use Laravel built in relationships, or, you can construct a giant query and join all the data together;

Like so:

```php
<?php
    
$projectUsers = ProjectUser::select([
        'project_users.id', // define aliases for all columns
        'project_users.user_id',
        'users.name',
        'project_users.role',
        'projects.id',
        'projects.name',
        'projects.start',
        'projects.finish',
        'assignments.start',
        'assignments.finish',
        'assignments.travel_out',
        'assignments.travel_home',
        'work_shifts.id',
        'work_shifts.role',
        'work_shifts.date',
        'work_shifts.start',
        'work_shifts.hours',
        'work_shifts.status',
        'work_shifts.remarks'
    ])
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'project_users.user_id'
    ->leftJoin('assignments', 'assignment.project_user_id', 'project_users.id')
    ->leftJoin('projects', fn ($query) => $query
        ->where('projects.start', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth())
        ->where('projects.finish', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
    )
    ->leftJoin('work_shifts', fn ($query) => $query
        ->whereColumn('work_shifts.id', 'project_users.id')
        ->whereColumn('work_shifts.project_id', 'projects.id')
    )
    ->whereColumn('project_users.project_id', 'projects.id')
    ->where('assignments.start', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth())
    ->where('assignments.finish', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
    ->distinct('users.name')
    ->cursor();

foreach ($projectUsers as $user) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried your suggested code and the efficiency (unsurprisingly) is far superior to my poor effort. I just need to work out how I can modify this to give me a similar structure for the results to the one I had previously. I believe I can make this work though!

Comment: I was able to group the  results by projects and then project_users, but sadly the way the assignments and work_shifts are being joined is not suitable for my requirements. I need to have a group of assignments and also a group of work_shifts associated with each project_user. Unfortunately I don't have the sql skills to figure out how to fix that   : (